# Create multiple static layouts or create a Database?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

I am developing an application where you have a lot of predefined concepts and you need to show it to the user. for example cook receipts where you have a lot of food receipts and you want to show the steps in a layout.

so my question is which of the following is better practice  **regarding application size and preformance**?

- would you create a layout for each receipt and when the user press on the desired receipt (`ListView`) you will show its related layout.
- or create 1 layout for all receipts and populate it from database
  where it has all the information of the receipts.

or is there a better way. please explain the reason behind your choice and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach will be better for

- App size
- Performance
- Maintainability

And the first is just a bad idea.

It's almost always a better idea to do things dynamically than hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have one more question, since it is predefined data, you prefer to insert all data when database is created or  download the data from the internet when the user use the app for the first time?

Comment: This depends on the planned update interval. For less than a month, I'd recommend downliading the data from the Internet. If no regular data updates are planned, include the data in the app binary.